# vb.net webbrowser navigate to url contained in richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, url, webbrowser-control, richtextbox

I have a richtextbox that contains URLs and a webborwser and a button. I would like that everytime i press the button, my webbrowser navigate to each url (one URL by line).
Here is my code :

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        For i As Integer = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines.Count - 1
            WebBrowser1.Navigate(RichTextBox1.Lines(i))
        Next
End Sub
```

My problem : It seems that the webbrowser navigate directly (cause other URL are loaded too fast) to the last website contained in the richtextbox...
How can i ask my webbrowser to wait the button to be clicked to navigate to the next URL ?

Comment: i tried too : 
' code' Dim i As Integer = 0
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(RichTextBox1.Lines(i))
        i = i + 1

Comment: If you only want to navigate to one URL when you click the `Button` then don't write code to navigate to every URL. A loop is obviously going to navigate to every URL.  Get rid of the loop.  You will need to remember the index of the line to navigate to and increment it each time.  That's what variables are for.

Comment: A variable inside the method is no help because it ceases to exist when the method completes.  Where do you usually put variables that need to remember data between method calls?

Comment: To be precise, a `Static` local variable could work, but I'd suggest just staying away from `Static` variables altogether.

Comment: thanks @jmcilhinney

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Shared i As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
             WebBrowser1.Navigate(RichTextBox1.Lines(i))
        i = i + 1
    End Sub
```

thanks again @jmcilhinney

Comment: No need to mark the variable as `Shared` if you keep it _outside_ `Button2_Click`. You only want to mark it as `Shared` if you want to persist the value in any instance of your form (or completely outside your form).

Comment: What jmcilhinney was referring to was to literally declare the variable as `Static` _inside_ `Button2_Click`: **`Static i As Integer = 0`** (see: [**`Static` keyword**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/static)). However your way is better.